# The average number(s) of A and B is (are) X and Y, respectively

Tags: grammar

'The average number of genes and transcripts is 100 and 200, respectively', or 'The average numbers of genes and transcripts are 100 and 200, respectively'. Which one is correct or better?

Comment: As you are talking about two different figures for different things, use the plural.